# Swift nsuserdefaults remove

Tags: swift, swift2

When i use removeObjectForKey of nsuserdefaults, 
also free the memory that the data occupies in ram?

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.removeObjectForKey("myKey")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties stored in `NSUserDefaults` do not occupy RAM. The are saved in the flash memory (like hard disk).

Comment: really nice thank you. however, removing the key value , free up memory . right?